# A problem about the difference of SHA-1 logical functions between wikipedia and FIPS 180-4

Tags: ssh, sha1, sha

[wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UUc0.png)

[standard manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39M55.png)

when calculating the SHA-1, we need a sequence of logical functions, f0, f1,…, f79,

I noticed that the function definitions in Wikipedia and the standard manual are different.

oddly, when I chose the ones in the standard manual, the SHA-1 result went wrong.

I used online sha-1 calculators and found that everyone uses the functions written in wikipedia.

Why?

Comment: the ft (x, y, z) function, when 0 ≤ t ≤ 19 for example, wikipedia uses OR operate, while the official definition uses XOR.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the truth tables for both versions of 'choose' (0..19) and 'majority' (40..59) (for 'parity' 20..39 and 60..79 both sources use xor). Please identify the rows for which the ior result is different from the xor result; those are the cases for which the two formulas produce different results.

| x | y | z | x^y | ¬x^z | ior | xor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

| x | y | z | x^y | x^z | y^z | ior | xor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Hint: there are no differences. The results are always the same, and it doesn't matter which formula you use, as long as you do it correctly you get the correct result.

In fact, on checking my copy of 180-4 this is even stated in section 4.1, immediately above the section you quoted:

> ... Each of the algorithms [for SHA-1, SHA-256 group, and SHA-512 group] include Ch(x, y, z)
> and Maj(x, y, z) functions; the exclusive-OR operation (⊕ ) in these functions may be replaced
> by a bitwise OR operation (∨) and produce identical results.

If something you did 'went wrong', it's because you did something wrong, but nobody here is psychic so we have absolutely no idea at all what you did wrong.

Comment: thank you very much. The truth table job, which I should have done by myself before post the question, are really awesome!